# ReadAffy() Taking Too Long

Tags: r, rstudio, package, terminate

I am using `R 3.3.0` on `Rstudio` on Ubuntu 14.04 and have installed package `Affy` successfully.

However, when I set the directory where `CEL` files are, (using `setwd()`) and give the command `cel1 <- ReadAffy()`, there is no output. I don't even go the the next line with `>`. It simply does not show any output.

Also, `Ctrl+C` and `Esc` are also not stopping the process. Usually `Esc` works for stopping the process on my system. Here is the screenshot: [image: Screenshot of the problem]

Also, when I try to quit the session, it takes too long to respond. What is causing this problem and how do I solve it?

EDIT:
I only have 3 `CEL` files in the folder.

EDIT #2:
I also applied it for single file, but takes again too much time. System monitor screenshot:
[image]
It is taking a lot of CPU and a lot of memory(in GB). What is causing the problem? I am using a simple command `ReadAffy(filenames = "N54.CEL")`. Why is that causing the problem? Any suggestion at all will be helpful. Kind of desperate here.

Comment: Force quit RStudio? Also, you may want to time the call on a few files, and then get a good estimate of how long the whole file read will take.

Comment: There are only 3 CEL file in the folder. It is not working for a single file as well. (Using `filenames=` ). Also, quitting the session takes a lot of time. I assume that's what you mean by force quitting?

Comment: Yes, and I realize it takes time to reload everything. I deal with very large gene expression data, and run into challenges - mostly when the system runs out of memory or when I execute something so computationally intensive by not experimenting on small sets first. Not sure what anyone else can advise you at this point. Remote debugging is hard.

Comment: @Gopala Could you speculate what might be the problem? I used `affybatch`  for single file as well, but not working. Any wild suggestion or direction can be helpful. Thanks

Comment: You can run `top` command in a linux shell (there are some options to sort by cpu vs. memory (I forget - try `man top`) and see what is going on (high cpu, or high memory). Your VM may not be configured with much memory and it is likely that you are running out of memory.

Comment: @Gopala You are right, the process rsession is taking almost 100% CPU and memory in GB. I also saw the same on System Monitor. But I am only giving one command of `ReadAffy`. Is it the problem of the package or my system? ANy dependencies  should install? Why such a simple command causing such a problem?

Comment: How big is the CEL file? Try another one that maybe is smaller?

Comment: @fanli You are right. this file is of 97 MB. I tried another file from another source that is of <25 MB and it worked in less than 3 seconds. So EITHER quadrupling the size is increasing the memory exponentially  OR there is some problem with the given .CEL file that can only be solved from the source. Will update when I get an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was some problem with the file itself. I got the file from a different source, and it worked fine.